# Configuring passwordless authentication in Microsoft Entra ID

Tags: entra-id

I've been working with conditional policies to lab up scenarios for deploying passwordless authentication and have been unable to figure out the best approach for new users.

If you create a policy for a set of target users that applies to all cloud apps and requires an authentication strength of passwordless mfa, you understandably prevent those users from being able to log in for the first time, reset their password and register their mobile devices.

One of the solutions in the official documentation describes using network locations to enforce the control for untrusted locations only.

*Target resources* has *User Actions* that apply to *Register security information* and *Register or join devices*, but do not offer the negation of those actions.

If you don't have trusted locations (i.e., remote-only users), how do you enforce the control but permit initial sign-on and device/mfa registration?

Answer (score 3):

> you understandably prevent those users from being able to log in for the first time, reset their password and register their mobile devices.

If you do not have trusted locations, you can use a *Temporary Access Pass (TAP)*.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/authentication/howto-authentication-temporary-access-pass

Comment: Hi, thank you for the clarification. I am still stuck in a loop, I can add a work account to my authenticator app and successfully authenticate with the TAP, but it suggests I must still go to https://aka.ms/MFASetup to complete the registration, which of course fails.